# Java and Regex to add some linebreaks

Tags: java, regex

So I have the following string that I want to inserts some \n before the numbers

```
1. Hello 2. Satuday 3.Kidding 4. sdsfjdfkj
```

I want to replace it to look like this

```
1. Hello
2. Satuday
3.Kidding
4. sdsfjdfkj
```

I was thinking something like this

```
variable.replaceAll("\d.", "\n");
```

Not sure how I could get the context I am find to replace

Comment: Sorry just read my post and realised I forgot to add my regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll` with a non-capturing regex, like this:

```
String res = str.replaceAll("\\b(?=\\d+[.])", "\n");
```

Given your string as an input, it prints

```
1. Hello 
2. Satuday 
3.Kidding 
4. sdsfjdfkj
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/lyw9HT)

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to replace every whitespace that has number and dot after it with new line. Try

```
variable = variable.replaceAll("\\s+(\\d+[.])", "\n$1"); 
// $1 is reference to captured group 1 which will contain number and dot
```

or

```
variable = variable.replaceAll("\\s+(?=\\d+[.])", "\n");
// (?=...) is called look-ahead, \\s+(?=\\d+[.]) makes sure that after matched 
// whitespace there will be number and dot
```

Answer (score 0):

somewhat slow, but easy fix:

```
string=string.replace("1","\n1");//  '\n' is the escape sequence for newline
```

then repeat for all numbers